# How to apply AND to all elements of a list?

Tags: python, list, boolean

Let's say Im storing a boolean value in list with a variable called `save_status`

I will be storing it like this

```
[ True, False, True, ...]
```

I want to be able to apply an `and` to all the elements of the list like so:
`True and False and True`, so that I know when all the elements of the list were True

Comment: have you looked into using `any` or `all`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `all` for "and" and `any` for "or":

```
>>> my_list = [ True, False, True ]
>>> all(my_list)
... False
>>> any(my_list)
... True
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. wasn't aware of these built in functions

Answer (score 3):

```
all([ True, False, True, ...])
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying another way:

```
>>> all_true = [ True, True, True]
>>> mix = [ True, False, True]
>>> sum(all_true) == len(all_true)
True
>>> sum(mix) == len(mix)
False
>>>
```